# PHP Check if all variables are empty

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I am submitting a lot of data from a form to a php script and I want an efficient way to check if all the data was submitted correctly.

### My Code

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$Submit = $_POST['submit'];
$Reset = $_POST['reset'];
$Topic_1 = $_POST['1'];
$Topic_2 = $_POST['2'];
$Topic_3 = $_POST['3'];
$Topic_4 = $_POST['4'];
$Topic_5 = $_POST['5'];
$Topic_6 = $_POST['6'];
$Topic_7 = $_POST['7'];
$Topic_8 = $_POST['8'];
$Topic_9 = $_POST['9'];
$Topic_10 = $_POST['10'];
$Topic_11 = $_POST['11'];
$Topic_12 = $_POST['12'];
$Topic_13 = $_POST['13'];
$Topic_14 = $_POST['14'];
$Topic_15 = $_POST['15'];
```

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['Name']) || empty($_POST['ID']) {` etc. can use `&&` to check for ALL instead of `or` => `||`

Comment: What does "submitted correctly" mean in your book?

Comment: @deceze did you closed that as too broad?

Comment: @MrA Yup. "Correctly" is not specific enough and depending on what exactly constitutes "correct", there are different ways of checking that. Can't possibly list them all here.

Answer (score 5):

```
$fields_names = array_merge(array(('Name','ID','submit')) , range(1,15)); /// instead of manually setting the numbered variables , used range function / @Fred-ii-

foreach($fields_names as $key)
{
 if(empty($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] != 0) // Making sure it's not 0 / @deceze
 {
  $error = true;
  echo $key . ' is not set';
 }
}

if(!$error)
{
  //Anything is set.
}
```

**NOTICE** 
I'm not sure that checking if the value isn't `empty` is enough.
Consider adding more validation rules.

Comment: Good answer. There's probably a way to set an array for all the numbered variables.

Comment: @Fred-ii- good point. we'll update.

Comment: You've got the error condition reversed, should be `empty` instead of `!empty`. Also note that "0" will be "empty", dunno if that's wanted or not.

Comment: @deceze - updated as well.

Comment: I kinda wondered that also @deceze

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, having more cooks in the kitchen, DOES make for better SOUP! ;-)

Comment: I would +1 again, for the mention ;-) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $value) {
        if (isset($value)) {
            # variable set
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
foreach($_POST)
{
   //test
}
```

if you also need the array keys look at the function of array_keys.
You will get an array of every key.

something like should do it:

```
$array_is_empty = false
foreach (array_key($_POST) as $x){
    if(empty($_POST[$x]))
    $array_is_empty = true
}
```

Sorry didn't had the time to test

Greetings
Martin

Comment: What's this `arrayis_empty` a new function?