# How to loop through a list of variables and check if their values is not empty in php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Good Day, I'm trying to check if the value of some variables which is passed from ajax is not empty. I have validated this in jQuery (ajax) but trying to add just an extra layer in php to check if the $_POST values are not empty. Below are the variables;

```
$_smChest           = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smChest'] );
$_smSleeve          = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smSleeve'] );
$_smShoulder        = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smShoulder'] );
$_smJacketLength    = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smJacketLength'] );
$_smArmHole         = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smArmHole'] );
$_smBicep           = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smBicep'] );
$_smStomach         = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smStomach'] );
$_smFrontWidth      = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smFrontWidth'] );
$_smBackWidth       = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smBackWidth'] );
$_smWaistBand       = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smWaistBand'] );
$_smPantsLength     = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smPantsLength'] );
$_smSeat            = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smSeat'] );
$_smStride          = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smStride'] );
$_smthighs          = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smthighs'] );
$_smKnee            = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smKnee'] );
$_smLegOpening      = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smLegOpening'] );
$_smJacketFit       = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smJacketFit'] );
$_smTrouserFit      = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['send_smTrouserFit'] );
```

I saw this question [(PHP Check if all variables are empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578968/php-check-if-all-variables-are-empty) and used this code to check if values of the variables are not empty;

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
          //Then Updated the users profile with the value and echo 1 for Ajax Response
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_chest', $_smChest);
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_sleeve', $_smSleeve);
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_shoulder', $_smShoulder);
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_jacket_length', $_smJacketLength);
           //(...)
           echo '1';
        }else {
          // echo '0' for Ajax response
          echo '0';
        }
    }
}
```

When i did it this way, the user profile got updated which is fine but the ajax response was `11111111111111111110` instead of `1` [see image below]

[image]

I know i can use something like this [below code] but the if statement would be really long. That's why i'm looking to use a more optimized approach

```
if (!empty($_smChest) && !empty($_smSleeve) && !empty($_smShoulder) && !empty($_smJacketLength) && //(...) ) {
    //Then Updated the users profile with the value and echo 1 for Ajax Response
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_chest', $_smChest);
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_sleeve', $_smSleeve);
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_shoulder', $_smShoulder);
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_jacket_length', $_smJacketLength);
    //(...)
       echo '1';
}else {
    echo '0';
}
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong or why i'm getting lots of `1s` and a `0`.

What i would like to achieve is to;
1. Loop through all the values of each variable and make sure none is empty and;
2. Make the response return `1` or `0`, if values are **not empty** or **empty** respectively

An idea on what i can do differently to make this work would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are echoing `1` if true and `0` if false in a for loop. On each iteration, it will print out `1` or `0` to the body of the response.

Comment: Yes i'm echoing `1` if true and `0` if false for the loop but in the response as seen in the image there is a `0` printed which means something is wrong somewhere. And i would actually love the response to be `1` is there is/are no empty value and `0` if there is/are empty value(s)

Comment: Have you tried outputting the value instead of 0 to see whats going on and where and why it is happening?

Comment: I just tried that just before your response @Blu3 by changing `1` to `Yes` and 0 to `No` and i got a response of `Yes0` ... Not sure why `0` is added

Comment: what i meant was try to echo the variable post to see what it is giving you, do not echo anything specific other than the value of the post

Comment: Blu3 i followed @Nigel Ren Answer and i realized i forgot to add a `die()` function to the ajax function which is why is returning additional 0 at the end of the response. Nigel answer was able to stop the lots of `1s` and made it just echo `1` and the `die()` removes the `0` at the end. Thanks so much for your assistance, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputing a 1 for each item updated, you may need to decide how you want the output to be generated, but something like.  This sets a value to be `'1'` and resets it to `'0'` if any item is empty...

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$ok = '1';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
          //Then Updated the users profile with the value and echo 1 for Ajax Response
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_chest', $_smChest);
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_sleeve', $_smSleeve);
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_shoulder', $_smShoulder);
           update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sm_jacket_length', $_smJacketLength);
        }else {
          // echo '0' for Ajax response
          $ok = '0';
        }
    }
}
echo $ok;
```

So this will output `0` if ANY of the fields is empty.  You may instead want it to be output `1` if any item is set.  You will need to set it to `0` to start and reverse the logic (i.e. set `$ok` if the `if (!empty($value)) {` branch.

A third option would be to do the logic to check the fields have values set, BUT move the update logic into a second loop which only gets called when all the fields are not checked as being not empty.

Comment: I will to make sure all item has a value as all the values are required. All variable much have a value for the output to be `1` and if one value is missing from all 18 variable, the output should be `0`. That is my goal @Nigel Ren

Comment: The above code only outputs 1 if all of the fields have a value.  It will output 0 if any are empty.

Comment: i'm getting `10`(instead of just `1`), so i tried changing the 1 in your example to `Yes` and 0 to `No` and when i tested it i got `YES0` as response. Not sure where that `0` is coming from?

Comment: Is this all of the code or is there something more afterwards?

Comment: This is all the code for the ajax.php ... the only code not included in the question is the HTML form code and jQuery (Ajax) code but the php aspect of the process is where the error is and this is all the code.

Comment: Everything else works perfectly fine up to this moment but just the additional '0' added to the end of the response is the issue now

Comment: Just as a quick test - add `exit;` after the line `echo $ok;`

Comment: Oh! ma'bad, this is on me... I forgot to add a `die()` or `exit;` .... I feel so embarrassed, working now. No more `0` in the end of the response. Thanks @Nigel Ren